# Finding the conditional probability of a pdf $f(x,y)=1/y$

Tags: probability

I am wondering if I did this right
find the conditional pdf
$E(Y|X=x)$ for the following

$f(x,y)=1/y$ for the $0<x<y<1$

I think the domain confuses me

I know that $f(y|x)=f(x,y)/f_x(x)$

so I know that $f_x(x)=\int (1/y) dy $ for $y=x$ to $y=1$

so I get $f_y(y)=ln(1)-ln(x)=ln(x)$

and I got $f(y|x)=(1/y)/(ln(x)$

then I got

$E[Y|X=x]= \int y (1/y)/ln(x))dy=
\int ln(x)dy$

$E[Y|x=x]=y/ln(x)$ then we plug in y=x to y=1

but I am not sure if this is  right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write all details to avoid mistakes. Let $x\in (0,1)$ be given, then for $\color{blue}{y\in (x,1) }$, we have

$$\color{blue}{f_{Y|X=x}(y)}=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_X(x)}=\frac{\frac{1}{y}}{\int_{x}^{1}\frac{1}{y}\text{d}y}=\frac{-1}{y\ln x}=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{y\ln(\frac{1}{ x})}}.$$

Next,

$$\color{blue}{\mathbb E (Y|X=x)}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}yf_{Y|X=x}(y)\text{d}y=\int_{x}^{1}y\frac{1}{y\ln(\frac{1}{ x})}\text{d}y=\color{blue}{\frac{1-x}{\ln(\frac{1}{ x})}}.$$